# find str in another str with regex

Tags: regex, mongodb

I defined:

```
  var s1="roi john";
  var s2="hello guys my name is roi levi or maybe roy";
```

i need to split the words in s1 and check if they contains in s2 
if yes give me the specific exists posts

The best way to help me with this, it is makes it as regex, cause i need this checks for mongo db.

Please let me know the proper regex i need. 
Thx.

Comment: You say you have tried regex & search already. Can you post the code you have already tried then people can help you fix the code?

Comment: in the beginning i tried to do on js with search or indexOf, but i  need that solution for mongo db with some good regex, so it is not relevant to enter the js code, i just need the correct regex.

Comment: Try not to include so many tags that are likely not really related to the question you are asking. Rather than give you a wider audience it can lead to answers you do not want (that happened) and possibly lead to your question being completely misunderstood and closed. Anyway, you have an answer now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possibly was something that could be answered with just the regular expression (and is actually) but considering the data:

```js
{ "phrase" : "hello guys my name is roi levi or maybe roy" }
{ "phrase" : "and another sentence from john" }
{ "phrase" : "something about androi" }
{ "phrase" : "johnathan was here" }
```

You match with MongoDB like this:

```js
 db.collection.find({ "phrase": /\broi\b|\bjohn\b/ })
```

And that gets the two documents that match:

```js
{ "phrase" : "hello guys my name is roi levi or maybe roy" }
{ "phrase" : "and another sentence from john" }
```

So the regex works by keeping the word boundaries `\b` around the words to match so they do not partially match something else and are combined with an "or" `|` condition.

Play with the [regexer](http://regexr.com/38mk6) for this.

Doing open ended [**`$regex`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/) queries like this in MongoDB can be often bad for performance. Not sure of your actual use case for this but it is possible that a "full text search" solution would be better suited to your needs. MongoDB has full text indexing and search or you can use an external solution.

Anyhow, this is how you mactch your words using a [**`$regex`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/) condition.

To actually process your string as input you will need some code before doing the search:

```js
var string = "roi john";
var splits = string.split(" ");

for ( var i = 0; i < splits.length; i++ ) {
    splits[i] = "\\b" + splits[i] + "\\b";
}

exp = splits.join("|");

db.collection.find({ "phrase": { "$regex": exp } })
```

And possibly even combine that with the case insensitive "$option" if that is what you want. That second usage form with the literal $regex operator is actually a safer form form usage in languages other than JavaScript.

Comment: good answer, but i get string "roi john", so every time i get the string i need to split it, there is a option to make this check without split the text, you know something like: db.collection.find({ "phrase": /\b{some String}\b/ })

Comment: @user3355127 No you cannot interpolate like that but there is now an added example coding usage to the answer that you can use for reference.

Comment: Excellent answer ! and explanation.

Comment: why do u choose to use in $regex ?, if you can use only in find ?

Comment: @user3355127 not understanding your comment. Other than to say that the actual `$regex` operation works better for general BSON type translation than using something that would be a native JavaScript form. This is how you use the operation in most other languages.

Answer (score 0):

using a loop to iterate over the words of s1 and checking with s2 will give the expected result

```
var s1="roi john";
var s2="hello guys my name is roi levi or maybe roy";
var arr1 = s1.split(" ");
for(var i=0;i<=arr1.length;i++){
    if (s2.indexOf(arr1[i]) != -1){
      console.log("The string contains "+arr1[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: my problem is that i always get 2 word or more to search in the second string, so i cannot make this solution

Comment: this looks like good solution for js, but i need this solution for mongo db, the way i know is with regex, but i do not which regex make that if you know other way, you can suggust